# How to find Fragment which was changed dynamically?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a `layout` with two `Fragments` in it. Second one loads dynamically.

```
Fragment fg = EmptyRightFrag.newInstance();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.right_frag, fg)
            .commit();
```

Then this second `frame`  replaces with another 'Fragment'.

```
    Fragment fg = MyClass.newInstance();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.right_frag, fg)
                .commit();
```

Finally I need to initialize the second `Fragment` by calling:

```
MyClass field = ((MyClass)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.right_frag));
```

But here I do get `java.lang.ClassCastException` stating `EmptyRightFrag` cannot be casted to `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you calling `findFragmentById()`? Directly after you added it?

The docs for `commit()` says this:

> Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit does not happen
>   immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be
>   done the next time that thread is ready.

This means that the `Fragment` will not be added for a while (at least not before your method has returned). Anyways you should probably not handle initialization this way, it's better to let the Fragment take care of that in `onCreate()` or something.

Comment: But what if I need to work with data within a fragment replaced dynamically?

Comment: Then it's okay to call methods on it but during initial construction it is probably better to use setArguments()

Answer (score 2):

Just call `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` before `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` and all will be fine.